# How to save data in two tables? (In Create)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

Good Day,

I wonder how to save the information in a create.

```
@model Request.Models.Chamados
@model Request.Models.InteracoesChamados 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
```

as shown in the two tables above only that of course does not work.
please give me an example of this because it confused me.

NOTE: So for clarity, I fill out a form and save to 2 tables when I hit save.

environment:
Windows 7,
Visual Studio 2010,
C #,
MVC3 + Razor Entity Framework

Comment: please provide the table names and column names and explain which daat you want to push from the UI into the database tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a few things here but for starters, you can only declare one model per view.

You could create a ViewModel that has both of those above, e.g.

```
public class ChamodosViewModel{
   public Chamados Chamados {get;set;}
   public InteracoesChamados InteracoesChamados {get;set;}
}
```

and then in your view

```
@model ChamodosViewModel
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I save? And I have to create another controller or can I use ChamadoController?

Comment: you can use same controller.   your action would accept ChamodosViewModel as parameter.  the view itself would need to have an Html.EditorFor(model) or similar.  Within your action in the controller you would save this.  I cannot say more without knowing what database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the Domain model for your view. Create a new **POCO** class which is specific for your view. Let's call it **ViewModel**, in general.

```
public class ChamodoVM
{
  [Required]
  public string ChamdoName { set;get;}
  [Required]
  public string InteracoName { set;get;}

  //other properties here as needed
}
```

Now in yout `GET` action create an object of this class and pass to the `View` method.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm=new ChamodoVM();
  return View(vm);
}
```

Make your view strongly typed to the ViewModel class.

```
@model ChamodoVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.ChamodoName)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.ChamodoName)

  @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.InteracoName)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.InteracoName)

  <input type="submit" />
}
```

When user submit the form, read the values from view model and assign it to an object of your domain modal and save. Thanks to MVC model binding. :)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ChamodoVM model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    var domainModel=new Chamodo();
    domainModel.Name=model.ChamodoName;
    domainModel.Interaco=new Interaco();
    domainModel.Interaco.Name=model.InteracoName;

    yourRepositary.SaveClient(domainModel);  
    //If saved successfully, Redirect to another view (PRG pattern)
    return RedirectToAction("ChamodoSaved");
  }
  return View(model);    
}
```